# InvalidPayload when posting MP3 for transcription when using Azure Speech to Text API v3.0

Tags: azure-speech

Using https://uksouth.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateTranscription/console, I posted this:

```
{
  "contentUrls": [
    "https://fsevideos.blob.core.windows.net/video-from-stream/Emails-From-Abroad-Min1.mp3?sv=2020-04-08&st=2021-05-28T11%3A40%3A20Z&se=2021-05-29T11%3A40%3A20Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=EC7SJ7n3HsvHzqXd7BeiAlxC660WuhievIo0kWTy08E%3D"
  ],
  "locale": "en-UK",
  "displayName": "Test1"
}
```

The response was:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
api-supported-versions: 2.0,3.0
api-deprecated-versions: 2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
apim-request-id: 961dac3d-0ded-4954-b355-029a2f997c13
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-store
Date: Fri, 28 May 2021 14:56:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "code": "InvalidRequest",
  "message": "A valid value is required for transcription.dataset. OR The value of transcription.Locale is a custom culture identifier. Custom cultures are not supported. OR Only absolute URIs containing a valid scheme, authority and path are allowed for transcription.contentContainerUrl.",
  "innerError": {
    "code": "InvalidPayload",
    "message": "A valid value is required for transcription.dataset. OR The value of transcription.Locale is a custom culture identifier. Custom cultures are not supported. OR Only absolute URIs containing a valid scheme, authority and path are allowed for transcription.contentContainerUrl."
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, the URL provided is publically available, what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en-UK is not a valid locale. It should be en-GB instead. You can find the full list of supported locales here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#speech-to-text